# Placeholder polyfill for Opera Mini

Tags: placeholder, polyfills, opera-mini

I am using [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js/) as a placeholder polyfill which works fine apart from in Opera Mini which I am guessing is because it's a proxy browser. Does anyone have a placeholder polyfill for Opera Mini?

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini [supports](http://jsbin.com/ronolo) `onfocus` and `onblur` event. So you can add handler to hide placeholder on `focus` event and show on `blur` event (simple case).

My tests for iOS Opera Mini and Android Opera Mini(last versions) shows that placeholder polyfill works fine only if you press `done` on device keyboard like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWbr3cV9hbg) from docs. If you will tap outside the keyboard the text input will lose focus, but blur hander will not trigger. Also not, that such behavior is true, because Opera Mini render run not on your device. More info [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/#Introduction).

My [test code](http://jsbin.com/ronolo), I create a form with 2 text inputs and add to first input handlers to attributes. For second input I add handlers using `addEventListener`.

HTML:

```
  <form action="">
    <input type=text value="Аttributes handler" onfocus="(this.value === 'Аttributes handler') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value === '') && (this.value = 'Аttributes handler')">
    <br><br>
    <input type=text value="" data-placeholder="Listener handler">
  </form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var listenerInputNode = document.querySelector('input:last-child'),
      placeholderText = listenerInputNode.getAttribute('data-placeholder');

  (listenerInputNode.value === '') && (listenerInputNode.value = placeholderText);

  listenerInputNode.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    (this.value === placeholderText) && (this.value = '');
  }, false);
    listenerInputNode.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    (this.value === '') && (this.value = placeholderText);
  }, false);

});
```

So I think there is really working polyfill for placeholder in Opera Mini, but `focus`/`blur` events **really** do not fire as you expect.

Comment: Not sure I have explained myself well. The placeholder text isn't showing when the page initially loads as it does in other browsers with HTML5 placeholder support or with the JS fallback. So for the input field I am not using a label I am solely relying on the placeholder text to tell the user what to input.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get round this using some UA sniffing to detect Opera Mini and hiding/showing the labels using an if statement. Can post code if anyone finds it useful.